# Looking for a online application with a lot of complex forms and grids

Tags: web-applications

Do you know any online application with a lot complex forms and grids ?

It doesn't matter what kind of appliaction it would be. I just need to show my boss some online examples because he is comming from desktop application development and he has no idea how to structure and manage presenting, saving and deleting of data. It's not about the graphics design.

Some economic application would be nice but as I sad it doesn't matter.

Do you know something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I would show applications like these:

- [Google Adwords](http://adwords.google.com/)
- [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)
- [Mint](http://www.mint.com/)
- [FreshBooks](http://www.freshbooks.com/)
- [Salesforce](http://www.salesforce.com/smallbusinesscenter/tour/)
- [Mailchimp](http://www.mailchimp.com/)

Comment: The Mint looks very good just I dont have a US bank account :( Do you know any other like this one ?

Comment: I've added two more links, you don't need US bank account :)

Answer (score 1):

[Jama Contour](http://www.jamasoftware.com/) is an incredibly complex web app based on the [ExtJS framework](http://www.sencha.com/products/js/). Sign up for the free trial or just watch some of the videos to get a sense of what the UI can do.

Answer (score 1):

http://guarddog.omnisite.com/Pages/Account/Login.aspx?OS&DEMO=true

This site features tables, graphs, menus, popups, etc.  There are forms in the Setup section.  It was created using ASP.NET in combination with DevExpress controls.  It isn't going to set the world on fire, but it's designed to be simple while doing a lot.  I'm a little biased since I wrote it, but I can also answer questions on how it was designed if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Documents](http://docs.google.com) - nothing to explain - drawings, spreadsheets, text processor, presentations.
[Acunote](http://www.acunote.com/) - online agile project management tool.

Answer (score 1):

googles igoogle.com webpage... It shows just about everything you are asking for as well as being extremely easy to add your own widgets to. Makes for a very good example of the possibilities

Answer (score 0):

try [paypal](http://www.paypal.com)'s registration form.

Answer (score 0):

Any web counter services (like [this](http://c5.gostats.com/summary.xml?id=1046507) one) or any internet market (like [this](http://rozetka.com.ua/)) seems to fit your requirements =)